# Windows 8.1 start screen backgrounds DLL File

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, start-screen

Where are the start screen backgrounds located in Windows 8.1 ? They used to be in imageres.dll on Windows 8. But now that Windows 8.1 has animated backgrounds, I can't seem to find them anywhere.